# Searching through thousands of folders with a search pattern in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

So, let me explain. I am working on an Node app which has to access some definite files inside folders. But the problem starts here; there are more than a thousand such folders with unique data stored in form of either text/html and it tends to grow even more in future. So, I decided to make a search section which can search through the folders. But here I am stuck. I had an idea of listing all the names of the folders in an array and work on them but I soon realized that it was a bad idea. Super slow! Structure:

```
app.js
public
    searchable
         folder-1 
             unqiue.html
         folder-2
             unique2.html
         folder-3
             unique3.html
         ...
```

And this goes on and on. I am new to Node.js and am trying to get things right. So, is there any way I can achieve this. Any new ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the array of folders and retrieving the files from the array.

Save the path to each files with reference to the root as an array dynamically using `fs` library and `cache` it.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let filePathArr = [];
getfilePathArray('src');

function getfilePathArray(path) {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        if (files) {
            files.forEach(file => {
                if (file.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
                    filePathArr.push(path + '/' + file);
                } else {
                    getfilePathArray(path + '/' + file);
                }
            });
        }
        console.log(filePathArr);
    });
}
```

Then you can search the unique file names `unique.html` from the cached array

```
const searchedPath = filePathArr.find(path=>path.indexOf('unique.html') !== -1)
```